# SSRS + e-accute (é) + Chart = Rendering issue

Tags: unicode, reporting-services, charts

I've got an SSRS report that contains a table and a chart.  In the table, the name Café shows up with no problem, but in the chart it gets escaped (rendered as `Caf&#233;`).

I'm not having any luck finding a solution to this, but I'm aware that its probably something easy I'm doing wrong/overlooking.  Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: What you have listed as "rendered as ..." looks identical to what appears in "the name .. shows up".  How is it rendering incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks for the edit bobince, I assumed my text would be literal and didn't check :-(